# what can i do if i deleted jetstream migrations?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I deleted the Jetstream migrations for a laravel project because I didn't know I was using them. Now I am getting an error message after I did a migrate:fresh

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'firmas.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = sX7DebaDgevsykUU5vI1IccIVp3epRKBmQ4vsOTi limit 1)
```

Is there a way to fix it? I wonder how can I recover them

Something with artisan?

Comment: Restore a backup or revert the change in your version control software.

Comment: the sessions table migration is provided by laravel itself, there is an artisan command to create that migration, `session:table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetstream has 4 tables, `users`, `teams`, the pivot and `invitations`, that you can find [here](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/tree/2.x/database/migrations), however you are looking for the laravel `sessions` table, that you can regenerate using

```
php artisan session:table
```